# Is it possible to check via reflection that type is in using block (Dispose is called)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to find automatically all code that not disposed properly. 
Is it possible to check via reflection that my type N is used inside using statement (Dispose is called)?

Comment: You could try a plugin like ReSharper for Visual Studio, it will at least help you with any week spots in your program, it will help you dispose properly.

Comment: Not all team members using resharper. And idea was to write test that will tell us that disposable object Dispose not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The closest you could come is to add a finalizer - possibly conditionally so that it's only included for debug builds - which checks whether or not you've been disposed and logs the problem otherwise. (You'd probably want to keep the stack trace on construction in this case, in order to blame the right code.)

Bear in mind that adding finalizers will cause garbage to stick around for longer - although in your `Dispose` call you could suppress finalization, so *correct* code wouldn't have a significant penalty, other than generating the stack trace on construction...

Now that's all assuming you want to do things at *execution* time. There are various static analysis tools (such as the [code analysis built into Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx)) which will tell you at *build* time if it looks like you haven't disposed of everything appropriately.